# Custom Url with Umbraco(other CMS) to point to existing website

Tags: angularjs, azure, content-management-system, umbraco

We have a running multi-lingual app hosted in Azure written in AngularJS. For managing some of the unsecured/public pages, we are looking for hosting another app with a CMS. So our app structure is would look something like:

**App:** www.example.com

**CMS:** www.examplecms.com

What we want to achieve is that dynamic content generated by CMS (different domain) for static pages be served using urls in www.example.com. Is it possible? We are primary targeting .net based CMS solutions but are open to other platforms. The static content is not too complicated.

Since the app supports multiple languages and most of the CMS solutions available offer multi-language support via subdomain.example.com or www.example.com/language/ directory structure, we want the custom url redirection to point to our app site (www.example.com).

Looking for suggestions you opinions or best strategies to work around this problem.

Comment: This is a tool recommendation / opinion-solicitation question. Not a programming question. Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

*This Q is off topic, nether the less...*

As you would essentially be running 2 entirely different web sites, yes everything would work just fine. The requirements are vague and very generic but any application/CMS could be setup in different domains and if you wanted requests made between them, allowing cross origin requests would allow sharing content/data.

Umbraco, like many CMS's supports multilingual sites using path prefixes as you mention along with any other method you are willing to write yourself.